# view.aspx must derive from viewpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a report in Asp.net mvc5 wep application...using asp.net control ScriptManager and ReportViewer In the View (ASPX) for show Report Viewer. i have followed this link to create the report
http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/01/how-to-display-rdlc-report-in-report-viewer-control-into-mvc4.html[^]

I am using razor view engine in my entire application but for report i have used aspx view engine.
can someone help me how to call .aspx in my razor view engine. In my view I have used this to call the ReportViewer.aspx....

```
@Html.Partial("ReportViewer")
```

ReportViewer is my aspx form that i have created in my views shared folder....
I am getting this error...

The view at '~/areas/administration/views/shared/reportviewer.aspx' must derive from viewpage, viewpage, viewusercontrol, or viewusercontrol.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanitory. In the linked article, the `.aspx` page `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"`, did you?

Comment: I tried it but it's giving me this error..... Could not load type 'IIUI.Recruitment.WebUI.Areas.Administration.Views.Shared.ReportViewer<dynamic>'